# Management Studio Missing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

There's no option of adding Management Studio in here. I tried every possible way of installing it, but couldn't get anything right. I installed it before also, it worked fine, but I don't know why it is not showing the option of installing the m-studio this time. Is there anything I m doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

With the SQL Server 2016 RC0 release Microsoft split out the installation of SQL Server Management Studio from the main installation of SQL Server.

You can download standalone version of SQL Server Management studio from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms).

The new version of the Management studio is free and regularly updated. Once installed, you need to download just the update.